# find all $k$ such that $k^5+3$ is divisible by $k^2+1$

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

That's it. I have a solution with substitutions, but it's tedious and not too generic. Is there a solution using some cool theorem for polynomials divisibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $k^5+3=(k^2+1)(k^3-k)+k+3$ we see that $k^2+1\mid k^5+3$ implies $k^2+1\mid k+3$.  If $k+3\not=0$, we must have $k^2+1\le|k+3|\le|k|+3$, which can be rewritten as $|k|^2\le|k|+2$.  It's not hard to see that this implies $|k|\le2$, at which point one can simply check the five possible values of $k$ (remembering to check $k=-3$ as well).

Remark (added later): This approach extends to any pair of polynomials in $k$ (with integer coefficients):  If the polynomial division of $Q(k)$ by $P(k)$ leaves a nonzero remainder $R(k)$ of degree less than the degree of $P$, then the set of $k$ for which $P(k)\mid Q(k)$ is necessarily finite, limited to the integer roots of $R(k)$ and $k$'s satisfying the inequality $|P(k)|\le|R(k)|$. In any given case there may be other (e.g., congruence) considerations that limit the search more efficiently; for example, $P(k)=k^2+k+2$ is always even while $Q(k)=k^5+k^3+1$ is always odd, so we don't have to search at all. It'd be nice to have an example where there are *some* solutions to search for that are cumbersome for this approach to find but are nonetheless easy to pinpoint by another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$k^2+1\mid (k^2+1)(k^2-1)k = k^5-k$$ we have $$k^2+1\mid (k^5+3)-(k^5-k) = k+3$$

Now $$k^2+1\mid (k+3)(k-3)=k^2-9$$

So $$k^2+1\mid (k^2+1)-(k^2-9) =10$$

So $k^2+1\in\{1,2,5,10\}$ so $k\in\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm 3\}$.

Comment: -2 and 3 are not solutions, but OK, checking only some of them is not much

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last transition. You added $k^2+1$ and got a tautology $10=10$, where does $k\in\{1,2,5,10\}$ come from?

Comment: Nevermind, for get about tautology. How do we get $k^2+1\in\{1,2,5,10\}$? $k^2+1 | 10 = 0$ so $10$ should be a multiple of $k^2+1$, let's check all divisors of $10$?

Answer (score 1):

$\!\bmod k^2\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{k^2\equiv-1}\,\Rightarrow\, k^4\equiv 1\,\ $ so $\,\ \color{#0a0}0\equiv k(k^4)\!+\!3\equiv \color{#0a0}{k\!+\!3}$

therefore $\ \color{#0a0}{0\equiv (3\!+\!k)}(3\!-\!k)\equiv 9-\color{#c00}{k^2}\equiv 10,\ $  so $\,\ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{k^2\!+\!1\mid 10}$

**Remark** $\ \color{#c00}{k^2\equiv -1}\,$ means $\,k\,$ behaves like $\,i\,$ so the above is essentially

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\begin{align} &0\equiv  z \equiv 3\!+\!i^5 \equiv 3\!+\!i\\[.4em] 
\Rightarrow\ \ &0 \equiv z\bar z \equiv (3\!+\!i)(3\!-\!i) \equiv 10\end{align}$

which has a natural interpretation in Gaussian integer arithmetic (or complex numbers).

As for a "solution using polynomials", the above computation is generic and it translates to the following Euclidean gcd (or ideal) calculation with polynomials

$\qquad\qquad(x^2\!+\!1,\!\overbrace{x^5\!+\!3\!\!\!}^{\large\color{#c00}{x^2\ \equiv\ -1}})\, =\, (\!\overbrace{x^2\!+\!1}^{\large\color{#0a0}{x\ \equiv\ -3}},\,x\!+\!3)\, = \,(10,\,x\!+\!3)$

using Euclid's $\, (a,\,b) = (a,\, b\bmod a).\, $ We could go further and extract [the Bezout relation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5Bx%5E2%2B1,x%5E5%2B3,x%5D) giving $10$ as a linear combination of $\,x^2\!+\!1,\,x^5\!+\!3,\,$ but there is no need to do so for the problem at hand.

Comment: You wrote a solution which alrady exsist

Comment: @greedoid I don't agree (and the other answers weren't there when I loaded this page)

Comment: Why is that........?

Comment: @greedoid None of the other answers use modular arithmetic, and the point of doing so is to emphasize the analogy with Gaussian integer arithmetic - see the Remark.

Comment: $k^2\equiv-1$ is really a neat idea, can this be generalized for divisibility by arbitrary 2-polynomials, not only this with almost trivial roots $\pm i$?

Comment: @kirilloid Yes, $\bmod x^2\!-a\,$ we can use $\,x^2\equiv a$ to reduce every polynomial $f(x)$ to a congruent linear polynomial $r(x)$. It's essentially an efficient what to compute the remainder $r(x)$ on dividing $f(x)$ by $\,x^2\!-a.\,$ Since $\,f(x) = q(x) (x^2\!-a) + r(x)\,$ we have $\,x^2\!-a\mid f(x)\iff x^2\!-a\mid r(x),\,$ so to test divisibility we need only the remainder (the quotient plays no role so it is a wasteful to compute it).  The same works not only for $\,x^2-a\,$ but for any polynomial. But in the general case the modular arithmetic is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with substitutions.

If $k^5+3$ is divisible by $k^2+1$, it could be expressed as $(k^2+1)(k^3+n)$, which if expanded, leads us to $k^3+nk^2+n-3$.

Now let's make another substitution by introducing another variable $a: k=-(n+a)$, which will get us $-an^2+(1-2a^2)n-(a^3+3)$. It is solvable for $n$ only when $D\ge0$ or $-4a^2-12a+1\ge0$.

Roots of the last [expression turned into an] equation are $-3\pm\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$, and since we are looking only for integers, we need to check $a\in\{-3,-2,-1,0\}$.

Now we can start unrolling our substitutions. For all valid values of $a$, solve $-an^2+(1-2a^2)n-(a^3+3)$ for $n$, and get values of $k$ directly as $-(n+a)$

$$\begin {array} {r|r} \ equation & a & n & k\\
\hline
3n^2-17n+24=0 & -3 & 3 & 0 \\
3n^2-17n+24=0 & -3 & \frac83 & - \\
2n^2-7n+5=0 & -2 & 1 & 1 \\
2n^2-7n+5=0 & -2 & 2.5 & - \\
n^2-n-2=0 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\
n^2-n-2=0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
n-3=0 & 0 & 3 & -3 \\
\end {array}$$